# Can someone explain why this gets a seg fault (C programming)?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
int load_byte(int memory[],int address) {
//This function works by finding the appropriate word then masking
//to obtain the relevant byte
int index,section;

    switch (address>>28) {
        case 0:
            index = address - START_ADDRESS;
            printf("index = %d",index);
        case 1:
            index = address - START_DATA_ADDRESS;
        case 7:
            index = address - START_STACK_ADDRESS;
   }

    section = index%4;
    index = index/4;
    switch (section) {
    case 0:
        return memory[index]&0x000000ff;
    case 1:
        return (memory[index]&0x0000ff00)>>8;
    case 2:
        return (memory[index]&0x00ff0000)>>16;
    case 3:
        return (memory[index]&0xff000000)>>24;
    }
```

}

START_ADDRESS has a value of 0x00400000 and the sample address I used was 0x00400002, it's just this function that keeps giving me a seg fault, don't quite understand why as the array in question has a size of 1000. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe because of an insufficient array size or out of bounds access? Try to debug your program

Comment: segmentation fault happens generally if you are trying to access null

Comment: A different bug: `>>` on a signed type like `int` will in general shift in 1-bits when the top bit is 1.  This behaviour is implementation-dependent, but most implementations I know of work this way.  If it occurs, this will cause problems for addresses >= 0x80000000.

Comment: By the way, pay an attention that you don't use `break;` in first `switch` cases. The control may reach other cases.

Comment: Desolator got it, thanks very much T_T, sorry about the stupid mistake

Comment: From the naming of your variables I suspect that these represent pointer values for you. `int` is the wrong type for that. It often nowadays is 32 bit wide where `void*` is 64 bits wide. Don't do pointer to integer conversion if you don't know what you are doing. If you knew, you would use `unintptr_t`: it has the corresponding width and is unsigned such that you have a clearly defined behavior with the shift operator. Arithmetic like that is not the right starting point to learn about pointers.

Answer (score 8):

Your first switch looks strange, only 0, 1 and 7 are handled. And there are no `break;` statements at the end of each case.

Answer (score 1):

The code:

```
switch (address>>28) {
    case 0:
        index = address - START_ADDRESS;
        printf("index = %d",index);
    case 1:
        index = address - START_DATA_ADDRESS;
    case 7:
        index = address - START_STACK_ADDRESS;
    }
```

Since the `address` is `0x00400002`, so the `switch` will start execution from `case 0`,
and you don't have any `break` in each `case X`, all the code will be run. That is, at last the `index` will equal to `address - START_STACK_ADDRESS`.

Maybe this was the reason.

Try to add `break`s between `case`s.

```
switch (address>>28) {
    case 0:
        index = address - START_ADDRESS;
        printf("index = %d",index);
        break;
    case 1:
        index = address - START_DATA_ADDRESS;
        break;
    case 7:
        index = address - START_STACK_ADDRESS;
}
```